# .NET Detecting Thread exits from external code?

Tags: .net, multithreading

I'm building a library in which to be consumed by a multi-threaded application. And I need a way to determine whether a particular thread is exiting.

Is there a way to add hooks or be notified when a certain `Thread` exits if you don't directly owns the thread?

Thread aborts are exceptional and thus I don't care about aborts, only proper exits.

This will greatly simplify the library if it is possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start a separate thread of your own and `Join()` it to the thread in question.

However, I don't see any simpler way to get an `Exited` event.
(Polling `IsAlive` is rarely a good option)

Comment: Hmmm `Join()` is a nice idea. A little dangerous but worth trying. Thanks!

Comment: @chakrit: If you call it in a dedicated "waiter" thread, it's not dangerous.  At worst, you'll just waste a thread.  (you may want a timeout)

Comment: do you happen know if it is possible that multiple threads call `Join` on the same target thread, or calling join on the same thread multiple times at all? If it is not possible, or undefined for whatever reason (it is in other threading implementations), then you might disrupt the program because your waiter library just "grabbed" the join from some other observer of the thread.

Comment: @Christian: I haven't tried it, but I can't imagine it that wouldn't work.  The docs don't say anything.